# How to access the innerRoot of a use in an inline SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've got a `<use>` tag in an SVG element inlined in HTML that I'd like to manipulate the contents of with JavaScript.

I'd like to be able to manipulate the SVG DOM within the deep clone produced by a `<use>` element. If this were an SVG document, I could locate the `<use>` and use .innerRoot to access the cloned SVG. But because the SVG is inlined (I think) the element is represented by an HTML DOM element, not an SVGUseElement.

Is there a way to "promote" the HTML `<use>` to its SVGUseElement counterpart, or otherwise access the innerRoot?

Comment: Can you share the SVG and JS code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you cannot access and manipulate the "cloned" DOM via the `<use>` element.  Maybe sometime in the future it may be accessible via the shadow DOM feature, but that's not possible right now.

If you want to manipulate the referenced content, you will need to modify the original elements that the `<use>` points to.